# VIM syntax highlighting 'buggy'?

Tags: php, html, vim, syntax

I switched from intelliJ to VIM a few days ago and I have a few problems with my syntax highlighting. I'm mainly working with php and html and in some files some of the `;` are marked with a red background (maybe meaning there is an error in my syntax?). This most likely happens when the `;` is followed by a comment `//`. I'm pretty sure there are no errors...

Also a few files do not provide php syntax highlight at all after a blockcomment `/**/` until the php tag `?>` gets closed.

Any idea what im missing? Also I'd appreciate suggestions on alternatives for syntax highlighting. It's hard to find useful stuff for webdev since VIM isn't that popular in that sector I guess.

Here my current vim settings:
https://github.com/raQai/.vim

I'd appreciate your help

**Edit:**

Here is the code thats causing the problems:

```
<?php namespace KF\LINKS;

defined ( 'ABSPATH' ) or die ( 'nope!' );

/**
 * Plugin Name: KF Attachment Links
 * Description: Adding attatchemts to post, pages and teams (Kong Foos Team Manager)
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: Patrick Bogdan
 * Text Domain: kfl
 * License: GPL2
 *
 * Copyright 2015 Patrick Bogdan
 * TODO: Settings for post_types with checkboxes
 */

new KFLinksMetaBox();

class KFLinksMetaBox {  
    const kfl_key = 'kf-links-information';

    function __construct() {
        if (is_admin ()) {
            add_action ( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', wp_enqueue_style ( 'kfl-admin-style', plugins_url( 'includes/css/admin-styles.css', plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) );
            add_action ( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', wp_enqueue_script ( 'kfl-admin-js', plugins_url( 'includes/js/kfl-admin-scripts.js', plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) );

            add_action ( 'add_meta_boxes', array( &$this, 'kf_links_meta_box_add' ) );
            add_action ( 'save_post', array( &$this, 'kf_links_meta_box_save' ) );
        }

        register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( &$this, 'kf_links_uninstall' ) );

        add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'kf_links_add_to_posts' ) );   
    }

    function kf_links_uninstall() {
        delete_post_meta_by_key( self::kfl_key );
    }

    function kf_links_add_to_posts( $content ) {
        $links = $this->kf_links_explode( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), self::kfl_key, true ) );
        if ( $links['is_active'] == '1' && count($links['items']) > 0 ) {
            $links_html = '';
            if ( !empty($links['title']) ) {
                $links_html .= '<strong>' . $links['title'] . '</strong>';
            }
            foreach ( $links['items'] as $link ) {
                if ( !empty( $link['name'] ) && !empty( $link['url'] ) ) {
                    $links_html .= '<br /><a href="' . $link['url'] . '">&raquo; ' . $link['name'] . '</a>';
                }
            }
            if ( !empty( $links_html ) ) {
                $content .= '<p class="attachment-links">' . $links_html . '</p>';
            }
        }
        return $content;
    }

    function kf_links_meta_box_add() {
        $screens = array( 'post', 'page', 'teams' );

        foreach( $screens as $screen)
        {
            add_meta_box (
                'kf_links_meta_box', // id
                'Linksammlung', // title
                array( &$this, 'kf_links_meta_box_display' ), // callback
                $screen, // post_type
                'normal', // context
                'high' // priority
            );
        }
    }

    function kf_links_meta_box_display( $post ) {
        wp_nonce_field( 'kf_links_meta_box', 'kf_links_meta_box_nonce' );
        $this->kf_links_meta_box_display_html( $post );
    }

    function kf_links_meta_box_display_html( $post )
    {
        $post_string = get_post_meta( $post->ID, self::kfl_key, true );
        $links = $this->kf_links_explode( $post_string );

        ?>
        <div class="kf-meta-box-checkbox">
            <input onClick="kfl_checkboxDivDisplay( this.id, 'kf-links' ); kfl_creaetLinksString();" <?php if ( $links['is_active'] ) echo 'checked '; ?>type="checkbox" id="kf-links-checkbox" value="1" />
            <label id="kf-links-checkbox-label" for="kf-links-checkbox">Linksammlung aktivieren</label>
        </div>
        <div id="kf-links" <?php if ( !$links['is_active'] ) echo 'style="display:none" '; ?>>
            <div class="kf-meta-box-full">
                <label for="kf-links-title">Titel der Linksammlung</label>
                <input onChange="kfl_creaetLinksString()" id="kf-links-title" value="<?php echo $links['title']; ?>" placeholder="Titel der Linksammlung" />
            </div>
            <div class="kf-links-header">
                <label>Name</label>
                <label>URL</label>
            </div>
            <div id="kf-links-items">
                <?php 
                foreach ( $links['items'] as $ID => $arr ) {
                    $this->kf_links_item_display_html( $ID, $arr, $links['is_active'] );
                }
                if ( count( $links['items'] ) < 1 ) {
                    $this->kf_links_item_display_html( 0, array( 'name' => '', 'url' => '' ), false );
                }
                ?>
            </div>
            <h4><a href="#kf-link-add" onClick="kfl_createLinkItem()">+ Weiteren Link hinzufügen</a></h4>
            <input type="hidden" id="kf-links-counter" value="<?php echo ( ( count($links['items']) < 1 ) ? 1 : count($links['items']) ); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo self::kfl_key; ?>" id="<?php echo self::kfl_key; ?>" value="<?php echo $post_string; ?>" />
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    function kf_links_item_display_html( $ID, $arr, $is_active )
    {
        ?>
        <div id="kf-links-item[<?php echo $ID; ?>]" class="kf-links-item">
            <input onChange="kfl_creaetLinksString();" value="<?php echo $arr['name']; ?>" <?php if ( $is_active ) echo 'required '; ?>placeholder="Name" />
            <input onChange="kfl_creaetLinksString();" value="<?php echo $arr['url'];  ?>" <?php if ( $is_active ) echo 'required '; ?>placeholder="http://..." />
            <input onClick="kfl_deleteLink( 'kf-links-item[<?php echo $ID; ?>]' ); kfl_creaetLinksString();" value="&cross;" type="button" class="button button-small button-primary" />
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    function kf_links_meta_box_save($post_id)
    {
        if ( !isset( $_POST['kf_links_meta_box_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['kf_links_meta_box_nonce'], 'kf_links_meta_box' )) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        $post_type = get_post_type_object( $_POST['post_type'] );

        if ( !current_user_can( $post_type->cap->edit_post, $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $new_meta_value = ( isset( $_POST[self::kfl_key] ) ? $_POST[self::kfl_key] : '');
        update_post_meta( $post_id, self::kfl_key, $new_meta_value );
    }

    function kf_links_explode( $string )
    {
        if ( empty($string) || !is_string($string) ) {
            $links['is_active'] = 0;
            return $links;
        }

        $explode = explode( ';$;', $string );

        $links['is_active'] = ( isset( $explode[0] ) ? $explode[0] : 0 );
        $links['title'] = ( isset( $explode[1] ) ? $explode[1] : '' );

        $links['items'] = array();
        for ( $i = 2; $i < count( $explode ); $i++ ) {
            $explode2 = explode( ';?;', $explode[$i] );
            $link = array(
                    'name'  => $explode2[0],
                    'url' => $explode2[1]
            );
            $links['items'][] = $link;
        }
        return $links;
    }
}
```

And here some screenshots:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jj3gluc7ok001hu/AABq_hRiKcbbDo1E0rKpP2Jxa?dl=0

Comment: This line is useless `set runtimepath^=~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim`. You can remove it since pathogen is already doing that. As for the syntax could you provide examples in the question that cause errors?

Comment: Which Vim version do you use, and please give reproducible example snippets (ideally supported by screenshots) that show the problem(s).

Comment: What would `php -l file.php` say?

Comment: $ php -l kf-links.php: 
_No syntax errors detected_

Comment: I  do not see the error with your runtime file configurations and the sample file

Comment: Which plugins do you have installed?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: me neither :D Might be because of nesting html in php?

Comment: @IngoKarkat: according to `vim -version` it is vim 7.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `:syntax sync fromstart`.

If that works, add `autocmd BufEnter * :syntax sync fromstart` to your `.vimrc`

Explanation:  if the syntax highlighter does not process every line of code from the beginning, it may not receive a critical piece of information to understand what type of code it's processing.  E.g., if you're in an HTML file and deep within a script tag, the syntax highlighter may not look back far enough to see the script tag and therefore processes your JS code as HTML.

Comment: Clear explanation and effective solution!